# CA0052 Could not identify plateform And CA0055 not targets were selected when Enable code analysis VS 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I'm using vs 2019 with .Net 5 and tried to run code analysis with MsBuild command, When I was using FxCorp its worked perfectly but fxcorp is deprecated I was getting below error

```
Warning CA0507  Post-build Code Analysis (FxCopCmd.exe) has been deprecated in favor of FxCop analyzers, which run during the build. Refer to https://aka.ms/fxcopanalyzers to migrate to FxCop analyzers.              Active
```

Now I changed with NetCodeAnalysis with .Net 5 (Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers -Version 3.3.3)

Now I'm getting CA0052 Could not identify the platform And CA0055 no targets were selected when Enable code analysis VS 2019

[image]
Thanks,

Comment: Please update the 3 errors mentioned in the tip in the post, in text form. We only see two errors from the screenshot, you provided a warning, which has no effect on us.

Comment: @JasonPan please check my edited I have receive only two error when I add  <RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis> tag in .Net 5

Comment: It seems you use the wrong nuget package, you should use `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers` instead of `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers`. Please try it, if you need further help, pls show your `.csproj` file, and I will update for you.